# Laravel form image not getting recognized as file

Tags: laravel, image, rest, eloquent, backend

I'm making an edit page for users using Vue + Laravel rest-api and I'm having a hard time linking an image to the image field of the users table.
The first issue is that it's not recognizing the image as a file despite adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  to the form. I looked up some solutions, but haven't found something useful.

The console.log(this.form.newimage) results in `newimage: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS...` so I pressume the format of it is good.

```js
 Backend UserController:
    public function update(Request $request, $id) {

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$id,
            'phone' => 'nullable|numeric|digits_between:5,15',
            'address' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'postal_code' => 'nullable|numeric|digits_between:3,200',
            'country_id' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'image' => 'nullable',
            'newimage' => 'nullable|file',
        ]);

        $data = array();
         (...)

        if($request->hasFile('newimage')) {
            $destination_path = 'public/images';
            $avatar = $request->file('newimage');
            $imagename = $avatar->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = $request->file('newimage')->storeAs($destination_path, $imagename);

            $data['image'] = $filename;
        }

        User::where('id', $id)->update($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use store file fun

```
if($request->image)
{
   $request->file('image')->store('image','public');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It says `Call to a member function store() on null`

Comment: add meta <form enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: and controller dd($request->image);

Comment: add enctype="multipart/form-data" <form action="route" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: chcke request dd($request->newimage);